# "Expecting More Source Characters" in my Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Visual Studio is objecting to the script below and returns a message that says "Expecting More Source Characters".  This I assume is the reason this script won't fire on the page.

Usually when I get this message in VS it means I forgot a semi colon.  However I don't *think* that is the case this time.  What could be causing this error?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
var Category = "animals";
var BaseURL = "http://localhost:61741/VocabGame/play?cat=";
var URL = BaseURL + Category;

    $.getJSON(URL, {
        tags: "Pinyin",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    },
    function (data) {
    $('#ChoiceA').append = data.nouns[0].Pinyin;
    $('#ChoiceB').append = data.nouns[1].Pinyin;
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're missing the closing `})` and also have a problem with your `.append()` lines. Try this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    var Category = "animals";
    var BaseURL = "http://localhost:61741/VocabGame/play?cat=";
    var URL = BaseURL + Category;

    $.getJSON(URL, {
        tags: "Pinyin",
        tagmode: "any",
        format: "json"
    }, function (data) {
        $('#ChoiceA').append(data.nouns[0].Pinyin);
        $('#ChoiceB').append(data.nouns[1].Pinyin);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery(function($) {
    var category = "animals",
        baseURL = "http://example.com/?cat=",
        url = baseURL + category;

    $.getJSON(url, {tags: "Pinyin", tagmode: "any", format: "json"},
      function(data) {
        ...
      }
    );
}); // This line is missing from your code.
```

Note also that the convention in JavaScript is to capitalize your classes. Thus, I did not capitalize the variables in this example.

Comment: +1 because your answer was helpful to me as well.  Thanks also for the tip about JS convention.